# When to use $ or not in a Vue HTML variable?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I don't quite understand whether I should use `$` or not in a Vue HTML variable:

```
new Vue({
   data: {
      a: "myData"
   }
});
```

I must use:

```
 <h1>My value is {{ a }}</h1>
```

or

```
<h1>My value is {{ $a }}</h1>
```

Which is the difference?. In the same way, I read:

```
{{ data }}
```

and

```
{{ $data }}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `$` (although you could). By convention, `$` denotes framework specific properties.

If simply try to use `{{ $a }}` it will not render anything because you haven't defined property `$a`. However it is totally possible:

```
data () {
  return {
    $a: "myData"
  }
}
```

The `{{ $data }}` is the example of such a property defined by Vue and refers to `data` object itself. Print it and you will see stringified (with JSON.stringify) result of entire data property:

> { "a": "myData" }

Comment: `{{$a}}` will not render anything even if you *do* define it and Vue will display an error in the console. From the documentation, "Properties that start with _ or $ will not be proxied on the Vue instance because they may conflict with Vue’s internal properties and API methods. You will have to access them as vm.$data._property".  https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ypKMmN?editors=1010

Answer (score 3):

I believe you use `$` to access built in (Vue) properties and methods. You use the other method when you want to access properties created by you.

```
var data = { a: 1 }
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: data
})

vm.$data === data // => true
vm.$el === document.getElementById('example') // => true

// $watch is an instance method
vm.$watch('a', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  // This callback will be called when `vm.a` changes
})
```

[Code sample source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

> **Note:** You shouldn't use the `$` for accessing properties/methods.

Answer (score 1):

All properties with `$` are instance properties meaning they are part of Vue itself. I am unsure you can even use `$a` like you mentioned.

It is not a good idea at least, since this denotes you are using an instance property instead of your own pre-defined data property.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties